# Asynchronous reset D flipflop code syntax error

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm writing a code to implement an asynchronous reset D flipfip, but the `always@` line is showing a syntax error:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps



module Dflipflop(
input D,
input reset,
input clk,
output Q

);
reg Q;

initial
begin    
    if(reset==1)    //clear the output (Q=0)
    begin
        Q <= 0;
    end
    else if(reset==0)
    begin
        always@(posedge clk) //syntax error here...
        begin
            Q <= D;
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

What could be the possible error, and is there a better logic for implementing the same ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would not encourage you to use the `initial` statement except in testbench. This is not synthetizable so it should not appear in RTL.

Then I think you are confusing Verilog with a standard programming language which it is not.

In Verilog, there is two classes of statements:

- processes, like `always` or `initial`
- assignment, with `assign` that allows you to directly assign a 'value' to a wire

In processes there can be distinguished two classes :

- Synchronous processes, `//do something` statements `begin end` will be evaluated only when an edge, specified in the `@`, occurs

  ```
  always @ (posedge clock) begin
    //do something
  end
  ```
- Combinatorial processes, `//do something` statements will be evaluated every time the value of a `wire` or `reg` used in the `//do something` block changes

  ```
  always @* begin
    //do something
  end
  ```

Here you have instantiated a process inside a process something that has no physical reality.

Another point, as described you want to activate the process only when `reset==0` so you put a condition to enter the process. Once more, that does not make any sense in terms of synthesis. The process should be activated and that is in the process that the conditions should be evaluated.

A classical solution for implementing a D flip-flop with asynchronous reset is the following:

```
module Dflipflop(
  input D,
  input reset,
  input clk,
  output reg Q
);
always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
  if (!reset)
   Q <= 1'b0; // Clear Q when reset negative edge occurs
  else
    Q <= D;    // Capture D in Q when clk positive edge occurs and reset is high
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have always block inside initial. It should be written like this:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module Dflipflop(
input D,
input reset,
input clk,
output Q
);
reg Q;

always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin    
    if(reset==1)    //clear the output (Q=0)
    begin
        Q <= 0;
    end
    else 
    begin
        Q <= D;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use initial(not recommended for synthesis) or always. One procedural block cannot come inside another. If you are really interested in designing a non-synthesizable logic and want to try out with initial, you can do something like this mentioned below. Both initial and always are procedural blocks.

```
  ....

    else if(reset==0)
        begin
            repeat(100000) @(posedge clk) 
            begin
                Q <= D;
            end
        end
    end
```